# Why is the text overlapping with its icon in QComboBoxView?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, model-view

I am learning the view-model design with PySide:

```
##start
# python 3, simple view-model example with Qt

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

# QAbstractListModel is an abstract class, it must be subclassed
class PaletteListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, colors=[]):
        super().__init__()
        self.__colors = colors

    # rowCount must be implemented
    # here we just return the number of elements in self.__colors
    def rowCount(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.__colors)

    # data must be implemented
    # index tells you the position of the selected item
    # role tells you in what way the data is going to be used
    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        value = self.__colors[row]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(10, 10)
            pixmap.fill(value)
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
            return icon

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return value.name()

# Use our new model
class Md(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.red = QtGui.QColor(155, 0, 0)
        self.green = QtGui.QColor(0, 155, 0)
        self.blue = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 155)
        self.model = PaletteListModel([self.red, self.green, self.blue])

        self.listview = QtGui.QListView()
        self.listview.setModel(self.model)

        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)

        self.tab = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.tab.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listview)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setLayout(layout)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
md = Md()
md.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Starting up the app, I got:

[image]

Looks ok, but when I click on the combo box, I got:

[image]

As you can see, the text is overlapping with the icon, why is this happening and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Works as expected for me on Linux, but without the weird tick in the top-left corner. Could that be forcing the icon to painted further over to the right?

Comment: Also work as expected for me on Windows 7.  There is no check mark for me either.